# Getting rid of atlTraceGeneral category shown in ATLTRACE output

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, atl

After upgrading to VS2013 I started receiving all my ATLTRACE2 messages in a "() : atlTraceGeneral - My output" format.

e.g.

```
ATLTRACE(_T("This is my data: %d\n"), 124);
```

... shown as

```
dllmain.cpp(1121) : atlTraceGeneral - This is my data: 124
```

I don't need any additional info. Is here some way to get back to the previous format so that the output would be just

```
This is my data: 124
```

Comment: Supposedly, you can use ATL/MFC Trace Tool to disable "Category and Fucntion Name" tracing. If this works out interactively, you can do the same programmatically in your code as well - to update initial state on your app.

Comment: I couldn't find ATL/MFC Trace Tool in current samples.

Comment: VS 2012 has it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\AtlTraceTool8.exe` Presumably, VS 2013 has it there as well. It can also be started from IDE, from menu Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the pointing out the tool. I had no idea that now it's included in VS tools. However, it manages ATL just for VS2012, not VS2013 and I need to get fixed in VS2013

Comment: Well, I don't have VS2013 to check - this is why I refered to VS2012 tool. It was there in VS 2010, VS 2008 and before. I assumed the same thing is in 2013 as well. The tool changes tracing interactively, and you of course can do the same programmatically as well using `AtlTraceXxx` functions.

Comment: That's the core issue, the tool was removed in VS2013.  And along with it, any option to suppress the extraneous chatter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only working fix is to undef ATLTRACE under _DEBUG macro and implement trace by yourself. Guys at Microsoft recommended [the same](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfc569ef-e229-4559-b245-ece2bba1e238/getting-rid-of-atltracegeneral-category-shown-in-atltrace-output?forum=vcgeneral).

The solution looks like this:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#ifdef ATLTRACE 
#undef ATLTRACE
#undef ATLTRACE2

#define ATLTRACE CustomTrace
#define ATLTRACE2 ATLTRACE
#endif // ATLTRACE
#endif // _DEBUG
```

with the following CustomTraces:

```
void CustomTrace(const wchar_t* format, ...)
{
    const int TraceBufferSize = 1024;
    wchar_t buffer[TraceBufferSize];

    va_list argptr; va_start(argptr, format);
    vswprintf_s(buffer, format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);

    ::OutputDebugString(buffer);
}

void CustomTrace(int dwCategory, int line, const wchar_t* format, ...)
{
    va_list argptr; va_start(argptr, format);
    CustomTrace(format, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}
```

Comment: I believe the second to last line should read `CustomTrace(...` instead of `Hooktrace(...`

Comment: @Anton, thanks it helped. I though there was some magic code w/ ATLTRACE but actually not.

Answer (score 3):

I went a different route -- I chose to edit the output like this (the message  only gets shorter, so no allocation required):

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
static int __cdecl crtReportHookW(int nReportType, wchar_t* wszMsg, int* pnRet)
{
    const wchar_t wszTrace[] = L"atlTraceGeneral - ";
    const int ccTrace = _countof(wszTrace) - 1;         // exclude L'\0'
    if (nReportType == _CRT_WARN)
    {
        wchar_t* pwsz = wcsstr(wszMsg, wszTrace);
        if (pwsz != nullptr)
        {
            int ccBuf = wcslen(pwsz) + 1;       // remaining buffer size (include L'\0')
            wmemmove_s(pwsz, ccBuf, &pwsz[ccTrace], ccBuf - ccTrace);
        }
    }
    return FALSE;       // always keep processing
}
#endif
```

And in the CWinApp-derived constructor:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    _CrtSetReportHookW2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_INSTALL, crtReportHookW);
#endif
```

and CWinApp-derived destructor:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    _CrtSetReportHookW2(_CRT_RPTHOOK_REMOVE, crtReportHookW);
#endif
```

For some reason, both the MCBS and wide-character versions of the hook are called with the same message, so only the wide-character hook is necessary even in an MBCS app.