# Get rid of annoying AtlTraceGeneral garbage (ATLTRACE VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc, atl

Could you all provide some help with getting rid of the annoying AtlTraceGeneral messages whenever I use TRACE in VC++ applications (MFC) in VS2015?

The solution presented here:

[Getting rid of atlTraceGeneral category shown in ATLTRACE output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508086/getting-rid-of-atltracegeneral-category-shown-in-atltrace-output)

simply does not work.

In fact because the later VS IDEs automatically grey out #ifdef areas when a macro is not defined , I get the effect of the `#ifdef ATLTRACE`  to grey out all the rest of the def/undefs etc of the solution proposed, which means `ATLTRACE` and `ATLTRACE2` simply are not defined beforehand.

Regardless, I tried defining myself and then undefining ATLTRACE but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thank you all.

Comment: It's not clear, what you are trying to accomplish. It sounds like you don't want tracing output, but then appear to be using tracing macros. Obviously, if you don't want trace output, then don't generate trace output. I'm having a feeling that you're asking the question because this is not what you want.

Comment: Dear @IInspectable if the answer was as obvious I wouldn't be asking it :)

I have included a link in my post and in there more information is given about the nature of this annoying 'feature' of VS2013 onwards. In short, along with any trace message the full path to the file that written it and the word - AtlTraceGeneral - is prepended. It is just such a nuisance and I want to get rid of this. As I mention, the answer given in the post I refer to does not work.

Comment: ATL's tracing implementation supports categories, *AtlTraceGeneral* being one such category. It is there to allow the AtlTraceTool to filter the output, for example. Not sure what the specific *issue* is you're trying to solve here. Getting rid of helpful diagnostic information seems like an unusual request. [Debugging and Error Reporting Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/debugging-and-error-reporting-macros) provides details that cover the infrastructure provided.